# How to start Express 4.x Server at Different IP Address?

Tags: node.js, express, iptables

I know this question had been asked a million time before, but even after a long research, I still haven't make it works. I have an Express application inside my VPS, generated by `express-generator`. I have do this in `bin/www` file:

```
 var port = normalizePort(process.env.PORT || '80');
 app.set('port', port);
 var server = http.createServer(app);

 server.listen(port, '0.0.0.0');   // set it to listen to all incoming IP
 server.on('error', onError);
 server.on('listening', onListening);
```

and I add some debugging line to `onListening()`, so I have this:

```
function onListening() {
   var addr = server.address();
   var bind = typeof addr === 'string'
           ? 'pipe ' + addr
           : 'port ' + addr.port;
   debug('Listening on ' + bind);
   console.log(addr)
   console.log('Listening on ' + bind);
}
```

I execute `node` and it prints :

```
{ address: '0.0.0.0', family: 'IPv4', port: 80 }
Listening on port 80
```

So, it means that my node successfully started. But the server keeps inaccessible (just loading.... in my browser). I know it is not about my firewall since I wrote a small hello world program from Node website, and it prints hello world in my browser. here is my working `hello world` program:

```
var http = require('http');
http.createServer(function (req, res) {
   res.writeHead(200, {'Content-Type': 'text/plain'});
   res.end('Hello World\n');
}).listen(80, '0.0.0.0');
```

Here is my netstat, node is clearly up and listening to port 80

```
Proto Recv-Q Send-Q Local Address           Foreign Address            
State       PID/Program name
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:22              0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      492/sshd        
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:25              0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      596/master      
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:27017         0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      5557/mongod     
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:80              0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      9747/node
```

And here is my iptable

```
 Chain INPUT (policy ACCEPT 108 packets, 10711 bytes)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination         
 843 77582 ACCEPT     tcp  --  any    any     anywhere             anywhere             tcp dpt:ssh
 17  2030 ACCEPT     tcp  --  any    any     anywhere             anywhere             tcp dpt:http

 Chain FORWARD (policy ACCEPT 0 packets, 0 bytes)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination         

 Chain OUTPUT (policy ACCEPT 1497 packets, 191K bytes)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination
```

Can anyone help ? Thanks in advance.

Comment: So, what is the actual IP address of your network card in the server?  And, how are you trying to contact the node.js server (with what URL)?

Comment: I access it using my ip address<115.124.92.84> given by my provider. I don't know my network card address. They use some kind of virtualization and the only device I have is venet0 with IP 127.0.0.2. I think that's not an issue since my Apache2 works at the same address, same port (80)

Comment: Do you have any evidence whether your browser request is getting to your Express app or not?

Comment: It sounds to me that your route handler isn't returning a response.

Answer (score 0):

well, after struggling for a day... and also read @jfriend00 and @robertklep comment. It turns out that my firewall setting is fine and there are problems with my database installation there, that's why it displays a blank screen with no log and only affect my VPS. Thanks for the comment!